# How to extend a namespace exported by jointjs?

Tags: typescript, types, namespaces, jointjs

I am trying to create custom element in jointjs, bu. I don't know how to extend namespaces / interfaces exported by the library so I can easly create a new jointjs element.

The error I am getting is:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> '"html"' can't be used to index type 'typeof shapes'.   Property
> 'html' does not exist on type 'typeof shapes'
>
> ERROR > joint.shapes['html'] = {};

```js
import * as joint from 'jointjs';

const BeerObject = (graph: joint.dia.Graph) => {

    joint.shapes['html'] = {};
    joint.shapes['html'].Element = joint.shapes.basic.Rect.extend({
        defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
            type: 'html.Element',
            attrs: {
                rect: { stroke: 'none', 'fill-opacity': 0 }
            }
        }, joint.shapes.basic.Rect.prototype.defaults)
    });

};

export default BeerObject;
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mM4jVN)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the error you are getting is because the `shapes` namespace does not have a property named `html` (which is exactly what the error message says). Thus, you will have to let the compiler know that the property *might* exist on the namespace.

To do this, you will need to utilize both [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) and [namespace merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces). This is the basic outline of how it can be done (note that the augmentation must mirror the structure of the library):

```
declare module "jointjs" {
  export namespace shapes {}
}
```

Now you need specify that the property `html` might exist, and that it might have an `Element` property. Since `shapes` is a namespace, and you *assign* to the property at runtime, you can use `let` to declare it:

```js
declare module "jointjs" {
  export namespace shapes {
    let html: {
      Element?: { /** the type of the custom Element */ }
    } | undefined;
  }
}
```

And that's it (you can also omit the optionality and `| undefined` if it suits your use case, of course).

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N91VJN)